# Stuck at inserting records into MariaDB conditionally

Tags: mariadb, insert, condition

I know about `insert ignore`. That's of no use, because MariaDB does not consider NULL to be part of the uniqude index.

Therefore I have to use `if ... else`.

But this code does not run:

```
select *
from Nodes 
where `Key` = 'FAQPage';

if not found_row() then
   insert into Nodes (`Key`, ParentId)
   values ('FAQPage', null)
end if;
```

How can I use `if ... else` to conditionally insert data in MariaDB?

Comment: Check the row uniqueness by the trigger.

Comment: @Akina, I didn't understand. This is a simple initial data script that I want to insert into a new database.

Comment: What is unclear? in BEFORE INSERT trigger chech does the row with the values to be inserted already exists, and, if so, forbid the insertion.

Comment: @Akina, this means that I should change the schema of my database, only because I want to insert a couple of rows as initial data. I don't think it's a good design. I prefer to be able to fix this `if ... else` issue.

Comment: @Akina, maybe I misunderstand something here. A trigger as much as I know is something that you define for a table, and whenever a record is inserted/edited/deleted, you get to know and act accordingly or even prevent. If that's the case, then it's part of the schema.

Comment: Oh, I see.. from this looking point you're right.

Comment: Shoulds like `Key` should be declared `UNIQUE` so that `INSERT IGNORE` would work -- _and it sounds 'correct' for your schema_.

Comment: @RickJames, indeed `Key` is unique. But per parent. So it's possible to have two keys that are the same but belong to different parents. And since MariaDB does not consider NULL in unique keys, it means that a key with a null parent can be inserted a lot of times. Which means duplicate records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO Nodes (`Key`, ParentId)
SELECT @key, @parentid
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM Nodes
                   WHERE `Key` <=> @key
                     AND ParentId <=> @parentid )
```

`@key` and `@parentid` are placeholders for the values to be inserted.

So if the row with the values to be inserted already exists then the subquery detects this, and none rows is inserted.

Comment: thank you so much. It worked. Interesting. A couple of things are new to me here. Is `<=>` equality check with data type? Also, why select null in the subquery?

Comment: *Is <=> equality check with data type?* [NULL-safe equal to operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) *why select null in the subquery?* You can replace this NULL with any (really any) synthactically correct expression. It is ignored anycase, only its presence/existence is checked. Some people uses 0, 1, `''` and so on... I like NULL.

Comment: Thank you. You made my day. I had more than 5 hours of struggle with this.